# Using toJSON on a ember.js record, is setting one of the attributes to null

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, ember-data, to-json

I've been messing with the [ember.js todoMVC](http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/emberjs/) example. Got it done and working just fine, but to learn some more I started modifying it.

I updated the model from this:

```
Todos.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
   title: DS.attr('string'),
   isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean'),
});
```

to this:

```
Todos.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean'),
    date: DS.attr('date')
});
```

(I'm using ember-data as well).

Added to the template to be able to enter a date and then updated the controller action for `createTodo` to this:

```
actions: {
    createTodo: function(){
        var title = this.get('newTitle');
        var date = this.get('newDate');     

        if(!title.trim()){
            return;
        }

        var todo = this.store.createRecord('todo',{
            date: date,
            title: title,
            isCompleted: false              
        });

        //this clears the input field value
        this.set('newTitle', '');
        this.set('newDate', '');

        //and save the instance of the model.
        todo.save();
    },
//...More code
```

Great, all works, so then I'm saving it to `localstorage` using the [localstorage adapter](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter).

This is where things break, the date is not being saved to `localstorage`, and its because of the `toJSON` and `serialize` method which are used in the adapter.

Specifically the adapter does this:

```
    _addRecordToNamespace: function (namespace, record) {
            var data = record.serialize({includeId: true});
            namespace.records[data.id] = data;
    }
```

Which takes the `_data` sub-object that is part of the record, and which looks like so:

```
//taken from the chrome inspector 
_data: Object
  __ember1386208719445_meta: Meta
  date: "12/11/2013"
  isCompleted: false
  title: "testing something"
  __proto__: Object
```

and returns:

```
Object {title: "testing something", isCompleted: false, date: null}
```

`toJSON` returns the same thing.

**SO TLDR && Question:**

Why do the methods `toJSON` and `serialize` set my `date` to null, when it clearly has a value, and that value is a string?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you said it was of type date, but you were setting it as a string, so when ember data tried to serialize it it was confused because it expected a date, so it would return `null`.

```
serialize: function(date) {
  if (date instanceof Date) {
    var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
    var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

    var pad = function(num) {
      return num < 10 ? "0"+num : ""+num;
    };

    var utcYear = date.getUTCFullYear(),
      utcMonth = date.getUTCMonth(),
      utcDayOfMonth = date.getUTCDate(),
      utcDay = date.getUTCDay(),
      utcHours = date.getUTCHours(),
      utcMinutes = date.getUTCMinutes(),
      utcSeconds = date.getUTCSeconds();


    var dayOfWeek = days[utcDay];
    var dayOfMonth = pad(utcDayOfMonth);
    var month = months[utcMonth];

    return dayOfWeek + ", " + dayOfMonth + " " + month + " " + utcYear + " " +
         pad(utcHours) + ":" + pad(utcMinutes) + ":" + pad(utcSeconds) + " GMT";
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea, once I saw that taking the `date` type out of the `DS.attr()` fixed it, I went and looked at the source for ember-data and saw what you posted.

Answer (score -1):

Your date format is not valid. Try "2013-02-07T16:44:57" instead of "12/11/2013".

Comment: The format doesn't matter. It's a string. But for thoroughness sake, I tried what you suggested, and it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Yes it's a string, but your DS.attr specifies it as a date, so it expects a certain format. Try the edit to my answer.

Comment: That's good to know about the DS.attr, but I don't think that's the issue. If I look at the record in the ember inspector, the date is there, its only when I refresh the page, and it has to retrieve the record from the adapter, that the date is no longer there. And I can repeat the error by assigning the record to the window object, and then in the chrome inspector calling `serialize()` or `toJSON()` on it.

Comment: Any chance you could put together a jsBin?

Comment: Your last comment, got me thinking, I removed the 'date' type specification from `DS.attr()` and now it works.

Comment: Great. Since you're returning it as a string, that should be equivalent of specifying it as a DS.attr('string'). If you're not doing any date manipulation you should be set (and even then you could convert it into the JS date format).